# what the relationship between com_insert, innodb_rows_insert, and handler_write?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a mysql instance, recently I found that there are something very strange.

when I show global status,

I found that the com_insert maybe x,

and innodb_rows_insert is 10 times of com_insert,

while handler_write is nearly 6 times of innodb_rows_insert.

it looks like this:

com_insert: xxx

innodb_rows_insert: 10 * xxx

handler_write: 6 * 10 * xxx

I'm a little confused about this.

Can anyone tell me what's the relationship of these three.

All insert statement the logic send to mysql is nearly equal the value of com_insert xxx.

Comment: how's their relationship? they are in separation :D totally different functions for different things, they are related only by being a setters on AWS.

Comment: while Com_delete, Innodb_rows_delete, Handler_delete and Com_update, Innodb_rows_update, Handler_update they are nearly equal. I think maybe they have some relation between each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert into tb1 select * from tb2

this statement only increase the innodb_rows_insert

and do not increase the com_insert

so it's because of there are some sql like above in logic.